# Update ML.NET trained Model in ASP.NET Core without restarting the app

Tags: asp.net-core, ml.net

Like the title says, I'm trying to retrain an existing ML.NET model in an ASP.NET Core web app. 
The setup:
I have an existing model.zip file on the local disk.
In Startup.cs I'm injecting the prediction engine pool service

```
    services.AddPredictionEnginePool<ImageData, ImagePrediction>().FromFile(
        "ImageClassificationModel", _modelPath, true);
```

by loading the existing model from the disk. The **_modelPath** variable indicates the path to the zip file, and the **true** parameter indicates that the Prediction Engine Pool should watch the model for changes. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net,

> The PredictionEnginePool service provides a mechanism to reload an
>   updated model without taking your application down.

I've also created a service that takes the path to some image folders and trains a new model, then saves it to the same location **_modelPath** indicates. That service is exposed through an API Endpoint.

**The problem:**
When accessing the **train** endpoint, the app works fine. It retrains the model and saves it to the indicated path. I can do this several times. However, if I use the model to predict an image's label, I'm no longer able to retrain the model. If I try to call the **train** endpoint again, I'm getting an error that says the model file is already in use.

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   '\MLModel\model.zip'
>   because it is being used by another process.'

The only way to update the model so far would be to completely restart the web app and call the train endpoint first thing.
**The expected result** would be able to retrain the model without restarting the web app.

Comment: Possibly calling `Dispose()` on your `PredictionEnginePool`, might release the model so that you can save the updated one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [`PredictionEnginePool<TData,TPrediction>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.ml.predictionenginepool-2?view=ml-dotnet) is just a specific implementation for pooling [`PredictionEngine<TSrc,TDst>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.predictionengine-2?view=ml-dotnet) objects. Like you can read in the docs `PredictionEnginePool` itself is not `Disposable` (only `PredictionEngine` is). But i think if you're using `PredictionEnginePool` you **mustn't** dispose those `PredictionEngine` objects because otherwise i think you'll ruine your pool.

So as far as i can see in the code of `PredictionEngine` the model reload should work fine and is thread safe because they're using the `FileSystemWatcher` class combined with some locking under the hood.

Have you tried updating the model zip-files manually? Because i would suspect the **train** endpoint in this case to not properly release the file handle on the newly created model file(s). Maybe you could also paste some snippets of this endpoint, please? I also saw that there is various logging going on while using the `PredictionEngine` with file watching active so setting your general [loglevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging) to `Information` or `Debug` might also help to see whats going on.